# how to remove compare product and my cart from right side bar in magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to remove remove product and right side bar...from magento 1.7..
I tried it from catlog.xml ....

I remove this ..

```
<reference name="right">
             <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/> 
            <block type="core/template" name="right.permanent.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">
                <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_right_callout.jpg</src></action>
                <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Keep your eyes open for our special Back to School items and save A LOT!</alt></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

but ..after removing ..this it is also showing on home...

How can I remove compare product and my cart from right pannel in magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really easy.

1. If you want to remove compare sidebar in right sidebar but **only on home page**:

Go to `/app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/layout/cms.xml`

Find the tag `<cms_index_index>` and add the following line:

`<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
<remove name="right.permanent.callout" />`

2. If you want to remove compare sidebar in right sidebar from **all cms pages**:

Go to `/app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/layout/page.xml`

Find the tag `<page_two_columns_right>` and add the following line:

`<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
<remove name="right.permanent.callout" />`

You can do this in cms.xml also. Find the tag `<default>` and add the following line:

`<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
<remove name="right.permanent.callout" />`

If you want to remove from category/product pages then you can goto catalog.xml and add the above same line under `<default>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways, simply use following from page where you want to remove

```
 <reference name="right">
      <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
      <remove name="right.permanent.callout" />
 </reference>
```